# How to install Meld with Homebrew on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, homebrew, meld

To install [meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) on Mac OSX I try to run:

```
brew install meld
```

but I got the following error:

```
Error: No available formula for meld
```

What is the right way to install meld?

Comment: you probably ought to switch out the accepted answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When this question was asked, [it was not possible using Homebrew.](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7978) They didn't support it yet.

There are alternative solutions to installing `meld` on OS X:

Use a different package manager, like [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/meld), which is mentioned in meld's installation manual, or MacPorts, mentioned in the issue in Homebrew's issue tracker.

You can probably also compile from source, but need to get the dependencies yourself. Installing one of the other package managers might be easier than that.

Comment: @meduz Changed the answer. Since I mention alternatives that used to work when this question was new, I decided against deleting the answer, as it might help those with the same issue with different software.

Comment: as of today, the correct answer is below: http://superuser.com/a/1177575/404225

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. The OP should unaccept it.

Comment: @Merchako Could you clarify why it's not correct? The first paragraph implies that it's (now) possible using Homebrew. Are the specific alternatives I provide no longer correct?

Comment: @DanielBeck, perhaps I was too lose with my words. Sorry. I think this answer is no longer the most relevant (as the votes show). The OP really needs to demote it. Also, it would help if you changed your typesetting to differentiate the first line from your original answer; it would be easier to scan.

Answer (score 134):

## Homebrew

You can now install Meld with Homebrew! On macOS, run:

```
$ brew install --cask meld
```

#### Other Homebrew Commands

I've changed the syntax of this answer over time to be more fluent. The following commands are equivalent and also work for at least macOS Sierra and High Sierra:

```
$ brew install --cask homebrew/cask/meld
$ brew install homebrew/cask/meld
```

You should **not** run the older `$ brew install homebrew/gui/meld` because it's deprecated by Homebrew.

Comment: upvoted! only 37 votes to go :P

Comment: The second step should be `brew install caskroom/cask/meld`. Check the brew warning when trying to run `brew install homebrew/gui/meld`: `Warning: Use caskroom/cask/meld instead of deprecated homebrew/gui/meld`

Comment: They both seem to work fine for me. Is there a reason to prefer the new way?

Comment: This worked for me, but I got a GTK error, which was resolved by running unlink /Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Frameworks/libz.1.dylib

Comment: FYI: `$ brew cask install meld` works for me on macOS Catalina v10.15.2 as of today 29 Jan 2020.

Comment: @Yuci are you not getting an error when launching the app due to it not being verified ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă No error, it is working fine. Just to be sure, I opened it just now :-)

Comment: This used to be `brew cask install meld`, but Homebrew changed their syntax in December 2020.

Comment: As of 2024, this answer does not work on Sonoma. The dependencies of meld haven't been updated to work on Apple Silicon. You can compile it from scratch, but it's a pain.

Answer (score 43):

**As pointed out by @meduz in the comment above, meld now compiles file in brew (haven't tested yet), please try it first, since my original answer is much older.**

Today is already possible install it using Homebrew:

```
brew install meld
```

I got a issue with pygtk, when I execute meld it says:

```
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
Cannot import: pygtk
No module named pygtk
```

I already have pygtk installed from lion, and needed to export it to work:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Add the above line to your ~/.profile to set PYTHONPATH automatically when you open a terminal window.

Comment: it compiles fine on the current version of homebrew, could you please edit your answer?

Comment: Note you will have to install XQuartz (from MacOS Forge) before installing Meld.

Comment: Note this is a lengthy install, took about 14 minutes on my (Ivy Bridge) machine.

Comment: Note, for me, this still resulted in an error, which was addressed in this post on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/455511/installing-meld-cannot-import-pygtk

Comment: In 2015 with Meld 3.14.0, XQuartz was not required for install. GTK+ appears to be running on the native X server? I'm not sure, but I know I don't have XQuartz installed.

Comment: See Kirby's answer for the updated commands

Comment: This generates the following error:
"Error: No available formula with the name "meld". It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask. You can access it again by running: `brew tap caskroom/cask`."

If users need to do something before `brew install meld`, you should say what.

Comment: I was able to successfully install with the above but when I try to run it I get

“Meld.app” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
macos 11.2.3 big sur

Answer (score 17):

On OSX El Captain you have just to run:

`$ brew install homebrew/gui/meld`

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer.

Comment: currently this fails with `Warning: Use caskroom/cask/meld instead of deprecated homebrew/gui/meld`

Comment: @jotadepicas It does. Instead you can just use `brew install caskroom/cask/meld` and it works (note: I already had xquartz installed).

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the current correct brew commands are

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
brew install homebrew/x11/meld
```

However after running those commands I ended with the following, which I know that I have overcome on other installations on different macs in the past.

```
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld:155: GtkWarning: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld", line 155, in <module>
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

But this time I decided it wasn't worth my time since I couldn't remember the exact remedy.

Instead I found a simple DMG installer and script from Alex Kras to launch the Meld application installed by the DMG installer.  The instructions are on [his site](http://www.alexkras.com/how-to-run-meld-on-mac-os-x-yosemite-without-homebrew-macports-or-think/). Note, though, that this DMG-installed version doesn't respond well to to the `git mergetool` input

Comment: I actually ended up abandoning the DMG version and went with the brew install. I could not get the DMG version to correctly understand git mergetool's output

Comment: Same problem as Kirby :(

Comment: On masOs Siera it just works w/o problem,
**$> brew install Caskroom/cask/meld**
==> brew cask install Caskroom/cask/meld
==> Downloading https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/download/osx-9/meldmerge.dmg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask meld
==> Moving App 'Meld.app' to '/Applications/Meld.app'
  meld was successfully installed!

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
brew install homebrew/x11/meld
```

or this

```
brew tap homebrew/x11
brew install meld
```

Meld is in Homebrew's X11 repository. Running `brew tap homebrew/x11` allows Homebrew to see Meld in that repository. (2015 answer)

Comment: Once installed how does one use meld?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, just type `meld` in your terminal

Comment: @Roy makes sense. Not sure why I never tried it

Comment: `brew install homebrew/gui/meld` worked for me. Looks like the package was moved?

Answer (score 3):

Don't install it using Brew. Do it this way instead. https://yousseb.github.io/meld/

Top reasons behind using this fork over Macports or Homebrew builds: Retina support (check the screenshot!) Latest 3.x series No hassle install (drag/drop like any other app) Integrates with OSX menu

Comment: @mwfearnley Ok. I moved my comment to the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As the formula for Homebrew disappeared i want to mention an alternative. There's [this build as OS X application](https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases/tag/osx-v1) which is simple to install. It was last built in December '14 and requires some tweaks if you want to use it from the command line. I have not yet tried to figure out how.

Comment: Thank you, this works. The homebrew business didn't work for me :-/, just complains about missing imports.

Do you know how to make that app available from bash commad line?

Answer (score 2):

It's been moved to Caskroom/cask, so run:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/meld
```

Comment: Does this still works?