# “Meld” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. MacOS Montery

Tags: macos, meld

I love Meld, and was able to use that in MacOs up to 12.x. I installed that using homebrew, as described here among other places: [How to install Meld with Homebrew on Mac OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/360007/how-to-install-meld-with-homebrew-on-mac-osx).

But since upgrading to Monterey, it has stopped working. Homebrew installs it just fine, but trying to open it, I get the following error: “Meld” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Is there a way around that restriction at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't open via launchpad for very first time.

1. Go to finder
2. Navigate to "Applications" directory
3. Controll + click or right click the meld icon
4. Click the open option there
5. It will prompt to confirm open and click the open button

Next time it will work with "launchpad"

Answer (score 4):

If you have an IT policy that prevents @sugunan's solution...

You can delete the apple quarantine entry with

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Meld.app/`

- [Source](https://github.com/yousseb/meld/issues/126)
- [Man Page](https://ss64.com/osx/xattr.html)